# Add class to form field on button click event Using DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I want to to add class to input field the button it click. I search a lot but I did not found a satisfactory  result. All I want to is to add class red to my input field when the submit button is click.

```
 <style>
    .red{background-color:red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myapp">

        <div ng-controller="formController">
            <form action='#' method="POST" formvalidation novalidate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td><input name="name"  type="text" id="name" ng-model="person.Name" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>age</td>
                        <td><input name="age" id="age" type="number" ng-model="person.age" required min="10" max="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I tried to create a directive on form element and define a custom directive
but its not working and fix-bug did not show any error is code.

```
var myapp=angular.module("myapp",[]);

myapp.controller('formController',function($scope){ 

});
myapp.directive("formvalidation",function(){
    var directive={}
    directive=function(scope,element,attrs)
    {
        var test=angular.element().find('#name');
        var button=angular.element().find("#submit");
        $(button).on('click',function(){

            $(test).addClass('red');
        });
    }
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: directive
};
});
```

Comment: use `ng-class` to active your class on `ng-click` event

Comment: I know that but want have idea of dom manipulation

Comment: Why DOM manipulation ?  it very simple with `ng-class` .

Comment: @gauravbhavsar is right, ng-class is built in directive of what behavior you want.

Comment: dom manipulation for form validation on basic i want to add a class on next step i many need value in dynamic environment .For that reason i need to know about dom

Comment: @MuhammadNasir If your changes is out side the angular context, then you have to call `$digest()` manually to tell angular to `watch`. So you have to call `scope.$apply();` after your changes to reflected all changes on page.